# Como guardar un HTML completo desde un webbrowser en vb.NET. Leer descripcion

Tags: vb.net

Muy buenas,
Estoy trabajando en unas plantillas de word que visualizo en un formulario, para ello utilizo un web browser transformandolo previamente a html.
Estoy obligado a dejar editable el HTML para que el usuario pueda modificar algun dato si lo viera necesario.
El problema me surge al intentar grabar esos datos modificados del webbrowser ya que pierdo las imagenes que tenia en el original.

He probado multimples formas de guardar el fichero, pero siempre pierdo las imagenes. ¿Podeis ayudarme?

Para abrir el fichero y pasarlo a HTML utilizo este codigo.

```
 Dim typeWord As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application")
                Dim WordApp As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typeWord)

                Dim htmlFormat As Integer = 8
                Dim Docpath As Object() = {.FileName} 
                Dim HtmPath As Object() = {Application.StartupPath & "\WordDoc.HTML", htmlFormat} 

                Dim WordDocs As Object = typeWord.InvokeMember("Documents", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, WordApp, Nothing)
                Dim doc As Object = WordDocs.GetType.InvokeMember("Open", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, WordDocs, Docpath)
                doc.GetType.InvokeMember("SaveAs", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, doc, HtmPath)

                WordApp.quit()
browser.Navigate(HtmPath(0)) webbrowser.
```

Esto me genera el HTML y una carpeta con las imagenes del documento.

Una vez modificado el fichero a la hora de guardar he probado, pasando a bytes y posteriormente construyendo el fichero con `system.IO.file.writeallbytes`, pasandolo a Stream con `browser.documentStream`, e incluso, aunque no me sirve (por mostrar un cuadro de dialogo) con `showsavedialog()`. Pero el resultado final al refrescar los cambios se pierde el enlace con esa carpeta de imagenes creada en la primera instruccion y no se como recuperarlas. Me ha ocurrido con todas las instrucciones.

Actualmente estoy volviendo a montar el fichero de esta manera, con el mismo resultado que con todos los anteriores.

```
File.WriteAllText(Rutanueva, browser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(WBFax.Document.Encoding))
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Buen día, para poderte ayudar mejor seria de gran ayuda si nos compartes parte de el código de como es que cargas tu formulario, como lo editas y lo que haz intentado para guardar. y además la plataforma para la que trabajas.

Comment: Tienes razon, ya he copiado un fragmento del codigo, creo que el problema es como recuperar entero un HTML del codigo y montar el fichero.